# Sum of Residue of Odd Function

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, residue-calculus

Recently, I am making use of the $\arctan(kx)$ (where $k$ is a positive real number) function in complex analysis. As I know, this function has two poles, one at $\frac{+i}{k}$ and one at $\frac{-i}{k}$.

After trying a lot of methods, the sum of residue of these two points seems to be zero (not as I expected). Is this a correct result?

If so, moreover, I would like to know whether the sum of residue at $+c$ and $-c$ of an odd function is always zero. (It would be great if a proof is provided as well)

Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\arctan(kx)$ does not have poles at $\pm i/k$, it has logarithmic branch points there.  Thus it does not have residues there.

For an odd holomorphic function with isolated singularities at $\pm c$, the residues at $c$ and $-c$ are equal.  If
$f(z) = \sum_m a_m (z-c)^m$ is the Laurent series around $z=c$, then
$$f(z) = -f(-z) = - \sum_m a_m (-z-c)^m = \sum_m (-1)^{m+1} a_m (z+c)^m$$
and in particular the coefficient of $(z+c)^{-1}$, which is the residue at $z=-c$, is equal to $a_{-1}$, the residue at $z=c$.

Comment: When I am doing contour integral of a function involving arctan(kx)(for the interest of applying residue theorem), is it necessary not to include these two branch points in the contour?

Comment: You have to detour around the branch cuts.